# How to use bootstrap with 16 or 24 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, customization, less

I need some help setting bootstrap 2.0.4 to be 16 or 24 column instead of the default 12 columns i can't understand what am i doing wrong i tried the customize option on the bootstrap site and i tried changing the grid variables in the variables.less file and recompile bootstrap.less using Crunch but  for both trials i still have the same result .it is still 12 columns !!!  when i try to set a div to be span12 it still takes the whole screen ?

Can anyone guide me to what's wrong i am doing or if someone can generate a 16 and 24 columns versions and send them to me that would be perfect

Answer (score 18):

This method is for an older version of Bootstrap - Version 2.3.1

Click this link to customize bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

You will find examples such as this. Change the parameters to fit your needs.

```
16 Grid system with Gutter
@gridColumns: 16
@gridColumnWidth: 45px
@gridGutterWidth: 15px
@gridColumnWidth1200: 52.5px
@gridGutterWidth1200: 22.5px
@gridColumnWidth768: 31.5px
@gridGutterWidth768: 15px

16 Grid system without Gutter
@gridColumns: 16
@gridColumnWidth: 60px
@gridGutterWidth: 0px
@gridColumnWidth1200: 75px
@gridGutterWidth1200: 0px
@gridColumnWidth768: 46.5px
@gridGutterWidth768: 0px
```

---

```
24 Grid system with Gutter
@gridColumns: 24
@gridColumnWidth: 30px
@gridGutterWidth: 1px
@gridColumnWidth1200: 35px
@gridGutterWidth1200: 15px
@gridColumnWidth768: 21px
@gridGutterWidth768: 10px

24 Grid system without Gutter
@gridColumns: 24
@gridColumnWidth: 40px
@gridGutterWidth: 0px
@gridColumnWidth1200: 50px
@gridGutterWidth1200: 0px
@gridColumnWidth768: 31px
@gridGutterWidth768: 0px
```

Comment: I assume you mean 24 in @gridColumns: 16 in
 '24 Grid system without Gutter'? Are the rest of the values correct?

Comment: Link no longer works, making this answer useless.

Answer (score 17):

For 24 colums you can split main div

```
<div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">nothing</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">12 here</div>

</div>
```

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/airsakarya/pen/MyeYvj)

Comment: this is a pretty decent work around I suppose. Will have to do for now.

Comment: I still don't understand, how does this make a 12 col grid?

Comment: it is not making 12 column grid. bootstrap splits 12 column your screen. col-md-12 equals width: 100%

Comment: This puts extra padding on first and last col-md-1...any suggested work arounds?  As easy as a media css to remove padding-left on first and padding-right on last?

Answer (score 10):

Simple enough to alter in less - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridCustomization

You'll want to change the variables there to what you want -

e.g.

```
@gridColumns: 24
@gridColumnWidth: 30px
@gridGutterWidth: 10px
```

If using a fluid-grid, you'll want to change these variables proportionally too, otherwise span12 will still take up 100% of the width and span24 will take up 200%

```
@fluidGridColumnWidth
@fluidGridGutterWidth
```

As stated:

> How to customize
>
> Modifying the grid means changing the three @grid* variables and recompiling Bootstrap. Change the grid variables in variables.less and use one of the four ways documented to recompile. If you're adding more columns, be sure to add the CSS for those in grid.less.

You can change the variables and download the new css right here:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html#variables

Here's a compiled example that should work for 16 columns (haven't tested, let me know how it works): https://s3.amazonaws.com/intenex/bootstrap16columns.zip

Comment: I did that in every possible way you can imagine i used the customization page and i compiled the less files using Crunch and simpless and when i look at the css file i find span16 defined but any element that has the class span12 still fill the whole screen as if i didn't do anything !! if you have a customized version with 16 columns can you send it to me.that would be really great . Thanks

Comment: Are you using a fluid-grid? If fluid, you'll have to change the variables 'fluidGridColumnWidth' and 'fluidGridGutterWidth' too to be proportionally smaller (divide by 1.33 for 16 columns) or else span12 will still take up 100% of the width and span16 will take up 134% of the width. Try this, see how it works for you: https://s3.amazonaws.com/intenex/bootstrap16columns.zip. If it still doesn't work, let me know and I'll test it out on my end and see what's happening.

Comment: Link no longer works, making this answer useless.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: Creating grids with custom number of columns has been restored, and can be done on Bootstrap's [customization page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/#grid-system).**

For reasons unknown to me, the latest version of Bootstrap (3.0.0/1) doesn't allow you to create grid different than 12 columns, which is a big shame.

What we can do currently, and which will in turn allow for creating more customized bootstrap packages, is to set up your own Bootstrap customizer.

Edit: I just tried it. Installing all the dependencies went quite smooth while sticking to guidelines on their Docs GitHub page.

Sample generated
[24 column grid](https://jsfiddle.net/3cLve/)

```
Editor required inserting some code along with jsfiddle link. There's no point in pasting anything though.
```

Answer (score 3):

**16 Column**

960px

45px *16 =720 Column

15px *16 =240 Gutter

1200px

53px *16 =848 Column

22px *16 =352 Gutter

768px

33px *16 =528 Column

15px *16 =240 Gutter

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and easy way I found to do 16 columns using nesting...

```css
.no-padding {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 no-padding">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      col
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- row -->
```

Comment: interesting approach, not sure if this would punish me later but im going to try it just to see how it looks on screen!

Answer (score 1):

I use Grid 30 columns for my project (Grid 24 and 100 also available)

https://github.com/zirafa/bootstrap-grid-only

some customization may be required depending on you requirement

Answer (score 1):

***Updated 2018***

Revisiting this question for the latest Bootstrap 4. Now that Bootstrap 4 is flexbox, and includes [auto-layout columns](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns), it's easy to **create layouts with any number of *n* columns**...

**16 columns**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                ... to 16
            </div>
</div>
```

**24 columns**

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                ... to 24
            </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/4sQGt2qKyr

---

Also see:
[N number of columns in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414441/n-number-of-columns-in-bootstrap/49415036)

Answer (score -1):

**Set 24 Columns:**

*960*
35px Column
5px Gutter

*1200*
40px Column
10px Gutter

*768*
29px Column
3px Gutter

Answer (score -1):

You can override the width attribute with percentage like this:

```
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="width: 6.25%">nothing</div>
```

It will even maintain the responsive capabilities.