# Twitter bootstrap - Different Number of Grid Columns Based on Screen Size

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a project that requires a 16 column grid for any display smaller than the large (lg) media query. The Large version needs to display the website using a 12 column grid.

Is there any easy way to use a 12 column grid for the large view and switch to a 16 column grid for anything below?

Comment: Check this out: [How to use bootstrap with 16 or 24 colums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591185/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-16-or-24-colums)

Comment: Thanks but I know how to use the Customizer to create the new grids but I don't know the best way to switch between the 12 column and the 16 column.

Answer (score 2):

If you create and download a custom 16-col bootstrap via http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system, and then put both in your `<head>` like so;

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="screen and (min-width: 1200px)" href="bootstrap-16.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then the custom one (I called it bootstrap-16.css) will load only when the browser is wider than the `lg` breakpoint - 1200px.