# How to Customize Bootstrap Column Widths?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns, sidebar

I have this, but I feel 4 is too big for my sidebar width and 3 is too small (it has to add up to 12).

```
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="col-md-4">
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
  <div class="col-md-8.5">
  <div class="col-md-3.5">
```

Is there another way to get a similar outcome?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Changing to a 16- or 24-column layout for more flexibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591185/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-16-or-24-columns

Comment: Is your site responsive? It's best to configure your content to flow more easily. Few sidebars are always the same width in today's web.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To expand on @isherwood's answer, here is the complete code for creating custom `-sm-` widths in Bootstrap 3.3

In general you want to search for an existing column width (say `col-sm-3`) and copy over all the styles that apply to it, including generic ones, over to your custom stylesheet where you define new column widths.

```
.col-sm-3half, .col-sm-8half {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-3half, .col-sm-8half {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-sm-3half {
        width: 29.16666667%;
    }
    .col-sm-8half {
        width: 70.83333333%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

For a 12 columns grid, if you want to add half of a column (4,16667%) to each column width. This is what you do.

For example, for col-md-**X**, define .col-md-**X-5** with the following values.

```
.col-md-1-5 { width: 12,5%; } // = 8,3333 + 4,16667
.col-md-2-5 { width: 20,83333%; } // = 16,6666 + 4,16667
.col-md-3-5 { width: 29,16667%; } // = 25 + 4,16667
.col-md-4-5 { width: 37,5%; } // = 33,3333 + 4,16667
.col-md-5-5 { width: 45,83333%; } // = 41,6667 + 4,16667
.col-md-6-5 { width: 54,16667%; } // = 50 + 4,16667
.col-md-7-5 { width: 62,5%; } // = 58,3333 + 4,16667
.col-md-8-5 { width: 70,83333%; } // = 66,6666 + 4,16667
.col-md-9-5 { width: 79,16667%; } // = 75 + 4,16667
.col-md-10-5 { width: 87,5%; } // = 83,3333 + 4,16667
.col-md-11-5 { width: 95,8333%; } // = 91,6666 + 4,16667
```

I rounded certain values.

Secondly, to avoid copying css code from the original col-md-**X**, use them in the class declaration. Be careful that they should be added **before** your modified ones. That way, only the width gets override.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-2-5">...</div>
<div class="col-md-5">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-4-5">...</div>
```

Finally, don't forget that the total should not exceed 12 columns, which total 100%.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

You could certainly create your own classes:

```
.col-md-3point5 {width: 28.75%}
.col-md-8point5 {width: 81.25%;}
```

I'd do this before I'd mess with the default columns. You may want to use those inside these.

You'd probably also want to put those inside a media query statement so that they only apply for larger-than-mobile screen sizes.

Answer (score 7):

**Bootstrap 4.1+** version of Antoni's answer:

The Bootstrap mixin is now `@include make-col($size, $columns: $grid-columns)`

```
.col-md-8half {
  @include make-col-ready();

  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    @include make-col(8.5);
  }
}

.col-md-3half {
  @include make-col-ready();

  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    @include make-col(3.5);
  }
}
```

---

Source:

- [Official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#sass-mixins)
- [Bootstrap 4 Sass Mixins [Cheat sheet with examples]](https://gist.github.com/anschaef/d7552885c0e1f127cf8830d3bbf6e4b1)

Answer (score 6):

You can use Bootstrap's own column mixins `make-xx-column()`:

```css
.col-md-8half {
    .make-md-column(8.5);
}

.col-md-3half {
    .make-md-column(3.5);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can customize bootstrap stylesheet, as in:

```
.col-md-8{
  width: /*as you wish*/;
}
```

Then, set the media query for that too, as in:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .col-md-8{
     width:99%;
   }
}
```