# Bootstrap Col width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Please, first have a look on the attached image[image]

I want `20%` in first column, but when I used `col-md-2`, it set `width: 16.6667%`
how I set column `20%` using bootstrap. 
Do I need to make my own CSS or there is a way to customise bootstraps3

Comment: How many columns do you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Customize Bootstrap Column Widths?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750907/how-to-customize-bootstrap-column-widths)

Comment: one columns is 10% and second column 20%

Comment: @JamesDonnelly so I need to customize in bootstrap

Comment: You can customize the boostrap CSS or you can just write your own CSS for what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap grid system is based in 12 columns.
Here there is the Bootstrap official doc http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

col-md-2 means that you want to assign 2/12 of the total width of your container, therefore 16.6667%

If you'd like to assign 20% you can add a class near to col-md-2 and than override the width, or set an in-line style.
Please note that if you set 20% is not a multiple of 12 so the near columns would never stretch 100% of width just using bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use custom classes (easy way), or customize Bootstrap grid system.

For creating custom class you could use something like:

```
.col-10p {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-20p {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

 .col-10p {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
 }

 .col-20p {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
 }
}
```

Then you will get 10% and 20% width containers respectively, and will be responsive like col-md-*s. These can be used just like col-*-* classes.

If you [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) Bootstrap or overwrite default grid classes it'll effect the whole project and will make unintended results.

Like this you can overwrite classes:

```
.col-md-2 {
  width: 10% !important;
}
```

Since using `!important` is not a good way to do things: you could use another approach like:

```
.width-10.col-md-2 {
   width: 10%;
}
```

which will give you desired effect. Just use the `width-10` class in HTML too.