# Bootstrap side by side divs, one with fixed size?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and trying to put 2 divs side by side. I know below method:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
    </div>
</div>
```

But i need the first div fixed width: 140px; What is the best practice to achieve that?

Comment: I almost checked all bootstrap 4 -> grid system related questions, I'm not able to find any question which asks this. If there's any can you please share the link?

Comment: Please read the other question and answers. https://www.codeply.com/go/x4TUJV8AFD

Comment: codely example is exactly what i needed, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it using **flex-boxes**. (Not using bootstrap)

```css
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
}

.first-div {
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
 }
 
 .second-div {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
  background: green;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="first-div">
    </div>
    <div class="second-div">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to customise your own bootstrap column widths then check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750907/how-to-customize-bootstrap-column-widths).

Comment: thank you, it works