# How to set custom column width in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried this [How to Customize Bootstrap Column Widths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750907/how-to-customize-bootstrap-column-widths) but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Has something changed in Bootstrap 4 so i can't do this anymore or is it more likely that i have an error in my code?

I also don't want to mess with Sass cuz I'm a begginer when it comes to front-end.

Sample of my code:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="">

        <aside class="col-sm-2 my-aside">  //tried <aside class="col-sm-2 col-sm-1-5">
        </aside>

        <section class="col-sm-8 fill-screen"> //tried <section class="col-sm-8 col-sm-8-5">
        </section>

        <aside class="col-sm-2 my-aside">
        </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comments refer to attached link.
EDIT: I want to do custom 1.5 column size and 8.5 column size because 2 is too wide for my sidebar and 1 is too narrow.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what layout you're trying to accomplish? You want exactly 8.5 and 1.5?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanna do.