# Creating a table of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a 16*16 table in html that holds div container in each cell. I'm not sure to what degree I'm allowed to mix jquery and pure javascript but what I have is

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var table = Doucument.getElementById('table');
    for (var i = 0; i <16; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow(i);
        for(var j = 0; j < 16; j++){
            row.insertCell(i);

        }

    };
});
```

This is adding a row to my table and then adding 16 cells. However I'm not sure how to add the div element to each cell. Perhaps theres a simpler way to do this with jquery? I'm not so proficient in jquery

Comment: With `Doucument`, does the above code really work or it's a typo?

Comment: It dosen't show anything right now, but yes I noticed that and fixed the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "Document" to "document", remove the loop indexes (i, j) from the insertRow() and insertCell methods, and capture the newly inserted cell so that you can populate it. I've set each div's ID to be a combination of row and cell number in the example below.

I should also point out that there are better ways to do this.  Tables should only be used for displaying data that requires tables.  Also, this kind of thing would ideally be done on the server side unless there's a reason for you to do it in JavaScript.

That being said, here is a working example using JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        var row = table.insertRow();
        for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell();
            var id = 'r' + i + 'c' + j;
            cell.innerHTML = '<div id="' + id + '">' + id + '</div>';
        }
    };
});
```

CSS (after reading your comment about controlling size):

```
#myTable TD DIV {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/ugm613zg/

Comment: thanks! do you know how i would adjust the height and width of the div?

Comment: is there a reason why 'TD' and 'DIV' are in caps? also thanks, your answer is very helpful!

Comment: No reason; they are case-insensitive.  "td" and "div" would be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a specific reason to create a "table" - it is frowned upon by UX and CSS experts. It is considered a better approach to consider creating a table-like layout using Div/Spans and CSS. There are frameworks available that can provide you this layout style out of the box.

One of the most popular ones is Bootstrap's Grid - and here are some layout examples - http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/. The benefit of using this approach instead of tables is that your layout will adjust better to screen size changes like say viewing on a mobile device (called responsive layout).

In the interest of full disclosure Bootstrap supports 12 columns out of the box - but modifications are available for 16 and 24 columns - [How to use bootstrap with 16 or 24 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591185/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-16-or-24-columns).

This is a longer route but a better solution than tables overall.

Comment: The question doesn't mention what it's used for - a table might be exactly what they're looking for.

Comment: Tables are used for layouts over the years for various reasons for older browsers performance and limitations on number of tables that could be nested were concerns. With modern webpages responsiveness (mobile and tablet friendly layout) is a concern. Table-less design has a lot of material over the last decade. Here is a comic strip that would help explain my point better - https://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/everything.html

Comment: I understand that completely. It's just that the question doesn't mention that this is used for layouts.

Comment: Besides layout what is the other use-case for HTML tables you are considering?

Comment: Just a normal table, to hold information worthy of tables. Why do you think bootstrap, which you advertise, has a whole section dedicated to tables.

Comment: The question talks about divs being in each cell of the table - grids would be better suited for handling this on devices of various sizes. To give you credit http://themergency.com/footable/ - yes there are "responsive" table styles available for smaller devices but not flexible as the grids using plain old divs.

Comment: I actually wasn't aware that using tables is considered not good. Its helpful to know what is considered standard practice today since I'm still learning  so thanks @Yazad Khambata

Answer (score 0):

And using jQuery, you could do the following.

```js
function addElems(ele, howMany, append) {
    var $items = $();
    for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
        var $ele = $("<" + ele + "/>");
        typeof append !== "undefined" && $ele.append(append);
        $items = $items.add($ele);
    }
    return $items;
}

var $table = $("#myTable").append("<tbody></tbody>");
var $trs = addElems('tr', 16);
$table.append($trs);

$table.find("tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var $tds = addElems('td', 16, "<div>My Div</div>");
    $(this).append($tds);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable"></table>
```