# Bootstrap more then 12 units

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

sometimes it works perfect, sometimes i have big problems with the following ..

Can i write it like this?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
         Testing ...
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
         Testing ...
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
         Testing ...
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
         Testing ...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Or does i have to seperate each "row"?

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
             Testing ...
          </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
             Testing ...
          </div>
           <div class="col-md-4">
             Testing ...
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
             Testing ...
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

in my current project the floating issn't correct so that the last column doesnt have the right margin..

Comment: create a demo with relevant code

Comment: you can test it by own?? Why US??

Comment: please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591185/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-16-or-24-columns#answer-15173226

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use smaller units instead of larger ones, i.e., `.col-md-3` instead of `.col-md-6` or use fluid layout.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  Col
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  Col
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  Col
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  Col
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  Col
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  Col
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  Col
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  Col
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  Col
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  Col
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have to use so many div and nested div? While this solution may be functionally correct, it is definitely an example of "DIV nightmare"!

Comment: It is `divitis` I agree. This is just a way!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your first example reacts exactly as it should. Any time you have more than 12 cols, the offending cols bump down to the next row (not `.row` which is different). Because you have 16 cols, the last group of 4 sits on next row.

To fit 16 sections on a single visible row (again, not `.row`), you will need to nest columns like so:

http://www.bootply.com/2VfLJXjcXt

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Test1
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            Test2
          </div>    
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Test3
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            Test4
          </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Test5
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            Test6
          </div>    
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Test7
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            Test8
          </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Test9
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            Test10
          </div>    
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Test11
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            Test12
          </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Test13
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            Test14
          </div>    
          <div class="col-md-3">
            Test15
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            Test16
          </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
```