# How to use bootstrap to create responsive two-column layout with left column really narrow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have been using bootstrap responsive 12 column grid layout for my website.

I have the layout like follows (stripped down version for example purpose)

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-1'>
      Left side contents go here
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-11'>
      Right side contents go here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need now, is that the left side column is wider than what I want. How can I make it fixed-length narrow and still use Bootstrap layout?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to go with Flexbox then.

Comment: Since it's layout, you can put the container with width you need inside the cell.

Answer (score 1):

A clean solution would be customizing bootstrap to have more columns, like this answer:

[How to use bootstrap with 16 or 24 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591185/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-16-or-24-columns)

Other alternative is using nested rows, but that could end up with problems like unused space, so my suggestion is customizing bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a nested row within a column
For eg-

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-offset-9 col-md-3"><!-- offset-9 leave space in left and start in last three of column --></div>

        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-11"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Nested row wastes the remaining space, you cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is an issue with how grid systems work. What they're designed to do is describe a fixed set of column widths: the content of those columns should expand to fill them. What you want is the inverse of this: you want the content to define the width.

You've effectively got three good options, and in order from least -> best in terms of getting what you want with the simplest markup:

1. Live with it (or have more columns as suggested, say 24).
2. Put the two columns of content in a block[1], apply `display:table; width: 100%;`. Make the two child items `display:table-cell`, use `white-space:nowrap` on the left-hand one and make the right-hand one `width: 99%`.
3. Put the two columns of content in a block[1], apply `display:flex`, and apply `flex:1` to the right-hand child item.

Flex is the best solution, but needs IE10+ if that's an issue.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

[class^="row-"] {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.row-1 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

[class^="col-1-"] {
  display: table-cell;
}


.col-1-left {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.col-1-right {
  width: 99%;
}



.row-2 {
  display: flex;
}

.col-2-right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <div class='row-1'>
    <div class='col-1-left'>Some content</div>
    <div class='col-1-right'>Some content</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='row-2'>
    <div class='col-2-left'>Some content</div>
    <div class='col-2-right'>Some content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```