# is it possible to take 13 column grid in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to take more then 12 column using  bootstrap and  css3 but its not showing a good result

so Is it possible to take more then 12 column in bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to do it in less, but you would want to use 16 or 24 columns instead. Here is an example:
 Setting your variables

```
    @gridColumns: 13
    @gridColumnWidth: 30px
    @gridGutterWidth: 10px
```

If using a fluid-grid, you'll want to change these variables proportionally too, otherwise span12 will still take up 100% of the width and span24 will take up 200%

```
@fluidGridColumnWidth
@fluidGridGutterWidth
```

> How to customize
>   Modifying the grid means changing the three @grid* variables and recompiling Bootstrap. Change the grid variables in variables.less and use one of the four ways documented to recompile. If you're adding more columns, be sure to add the CSS for those in grid.less.

You can change the variables and download the new css right here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html#variables

Here's a compiled example that should work for 16 columns (haven't tested, let me know how it works): https://s3.amazonaws.com/intenex/bootstrap16columns.zip

Comment: Answer seems to be copy pasted from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591185/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-16-or-24-columns

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know Bootstrap was designed as a 12 column grid only. I'm not sure what sort of UI issues your having, but, have a look at the responsive side of Bootstraps grid as well.

There are other frameworks that have 16 columns, eg.[Semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html).

Hopefully this helps.