# N number of columns in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a online shop. I need to have 3 items per row with some space left over. So my idea was a column of 9 with 3 child columns of. Then I have 3 columns left over from the 9 for whaterever else I choose.

My issue is in a few categories I have 4/5 items. So they all appear on 1 line. How can I solved this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
          @foreach ($items as $item)
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="list-image" src="{{$item->image}}">
            </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Nope, the inner columns don't consider the outer as a starting point for their division.

Comment: They'll all have to be `col-4` if you want 3 per row

Comment: But but what if i only want 9 columns used  per row in total. (3 per item)

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. Do you have an example?

Comment: http://graphics.cs.wisc.edu/WP/javascript15/files/2015/12/LayoutDiagram.png something like this. But I want another section to the right for text but there won't be text in every row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [auto-layout columns](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) which are **not restricted to 12**.

Use `.col-auto` for columns that size to their content..

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <img class="list-image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <img class="list-image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <img class="list-image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                ... to n
            </div>
</div>
```

***or,*** use `.col` for columns that evenly fill across the row..

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img class="list-image">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img class="list-image">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                ... to n
            </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/wqoiLlSUc5

Comment: Please accept an answer so others know the question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Every row in bootstrap is 12 cols. It does not matter if you take you top row only 9 cols. Inside the 9 cols row you will have 12 cols again. Best thing in your case to do is calculate floor 12/<#items>. Then user the value to determine your col size.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use all 12 columns. 12 columns is just the maximum that's available. There is a number of ways to achieve the desired spacing between columns when you don't utilize all 12 of the available columns like it is in your case.

Two of the possible options would be to use the `justify-content-around` class or the `justify-content-between` class on the row like so (click "run code snippet" below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container bg-light my-3">
   <h3 class="text-center pt-2">row justify-content-around</h3>
   <div class="row justify-content-around">
       <div class="col-md-3 bg-warning">Column 1</div>
       <div class="col-md-3 bg-primary">Column 2</div>
       <div class="col-md-3 bg-secondary">Column 3</div>
   </div>
   <h3 class="text-center pt-4">row justify-content-between</h3>
   <div class="row justify-content-between">
       <div class="col-md-3 bg-warning">Column 1</div>
       <div class="col-md-3 bg-primary">Column 2</div>
       <div class="col-md-3 bg-secondary">Column 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, no unnecessary nesting is needed there.

That's because those classes take advantage of the flexbox properties.