# How to indent between div blocks so that they are not back to back?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I just started learning bootstrap (version 3), so there are difficulties (even in terminology). Such a question: how to separate div blocks from each other? I mean that the content of these blocks on the site should not be back to back. For example, I have 2 divs, how can I write so that the content on the site is separate?

```html
<body>

    <div class="row form-inline">
        <div class="col-sm-15">
            <label class="small">Options:</label>
            <select class="form-control" title="" name="testGroup" id="testGroup194">
                <option selected="selected" value="">ALL</option>
                <option title="Option A" value="14">Option A</option>
                <option title="Option B" value="15">Option B</option>
                <option title="Option C" value="16">Option C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-16">
            <label class="small">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="patientName">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Also a question on code (it's not mine). What does col-sm-15 and col-sm-16 mean? In the grid, a maximum of 12 columns is possible, but there are more.

Comment: are you referring to "gutters" (space between `col`s) ?

Comment: @smwhr, yes, I'm talking about it

Answer (score 1):

Since you are referring to gutters, you can now check the corresponding documentation at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters.

As for `col-md-16` this is `auto-layout-columns`, new in Boostrap 4 : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

See this question for more info : [N number of columns in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414441/n-number-of-columns-in-bootstrap-4/49415036#49415036)

Comment: thanks, but as I wrote above I need a solution for bootstrap version 3

Comment: Oh, sorry, I got mixed up because you're not supposed to have more than 12 cols in BS3. So I ended up on BS4 doc. Now I remember : BS3 gutters are a pain.